# Jenkins not starting on CentOS after installation

Tags: jenkins, centos

I installed jenkins by following the URL below. Everything is successful, I have also installed Java. But it is not starting up

https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/

[image]

Comment: I see there is some `createFile...` error mentioned. Check for permission issues

Comment: Need more info: jenkins logs, system logs. Which java version and system version you are running on?